# Is it possible to render the content of a file without using eval in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, rendering, eval, file-get-contents

I'm trying to create a simple framework in PHP which will include a file (index.bel) and render the variables within the file. For instance, the index.bel could contain the following:

```
<h1>{$variable_name}</h1>
```

How would I achieve this without using eval or demanding the users of the framework to type index.bel like this:

```
$index = "<h1>{$variable_name}</h1>";
```

In other words: Is it possible to render the content of a file without using eval? A working solution for my problem is this:

index.php:

```
<?php
$variable_name = 'Welcome!';
eval ('print "'.file_get_contents ("index.bel").'";');
```

index.bel:

```
<h1>{$variable_name}</h1>
```

Comment: What's wrong with some regex to find and `str_replace`...

Comment: A template engine class would be better to include. SMARTY for example (I feel the hate for SMARTY coming through) least a template engine supports your own framework; it compliments it.

Comment: USe a templating engine.

Answer (score 4):

I know many have recommended you to add template engine, **but** if you want to create your own, easiest way in your case is use str_replace:

```
$index        = file_get_contents ("index.bel");
$replace_from = array ('$variable_a', '$variable_b');
$replace_to   = array ($var_a_value, $var_b_value);
$index        = str_replace($replace_from,$replace_to,$index);
```

Now that is for simple variable replace, but you soon want more tags, more functionality, and one way to do things like these are using `preg_replace_callback`. You might want to take a look at it, as it will eventually make possible to replace variables, include other files `{include:file.bel}`, replace text like `{img:foo.png}`.

**EDIT**: reading more your comments, you are on your way to create own framework. Take a look at `preg_replace_callback` as it gives you more ways to handle things.

Very simple example here:

```
...
$index = preg_replace_callback ('/{([^}]+)}>/i', 'preg_callback', $index);
...

function preg_callback($matches) {
  var_dump($matches);

  $s = preg_split("/:/",$matches[1]);  // string matched split by :
  $f = 'func_'.strtolower($s[0]);      // all functions are like func_img,func_include, ...
  $ret = $f($s);                       // call function with all split parameters

  return $ret;
}

function func_img($s) {
  return '<img src="'.$s[1].'" />';
}
```

From here you can improve this (many ways), for example dividing all functionalities to classes, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but why are you making your own framework? The code you provided clearly looks like Smarty Template. You could try to look how they did it.

A possible way to run those code is splitting them into pieces. You split on the dollar sign and the next symbol which is not an underscore, a letter or an number. Once you did that. You could parse it into a variable.

$var = 'variable_name'; // Split it first

echo $$var; // Get the given variable

Did you mean something like this?